# SQL: How to execute stored procedure that returns values where column is "IN" parameter?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have table and I need stored procedure to return all rows when specific column value is "IN" parameter not "=" parameter.

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestGetDataInParameter] 
    @MyParameter nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *  
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE MyColum IN (@MyParameter)
END
```

I have C# code that executes this stored procedure and I don't know which format I should pass the parameter in to get the query executed correctly.

Comment: Looks like `MyColumn` is `varchar` so you should pass the parameter as `string` from C#

Comment: Yeah, I mean should the string be like "val1, val2,.." or " 'val1', 'val2' "
I'm asking about the input format that I should send to the procedure.

Comment: Should be like- `"'val1', 'val2'"`. Remove the extra spaces within the quotes.

Comment: This will not work without dynamic SQL, since regardless of how you format the string, SQL will interpret it as a string... Realistically you should be passing a datatable and have the stored procedure's parameter be a TVP but failing that you will need a string splitter. Regardless of what you do, you will need reconstruct how the stored procedure is written.

Comment: @ZLK Yeah none of the formats I tried worked, can you please help me witht he changes I need to make to the stored procedure? it will be great if you can provide an example or link that shows examples for how to do that.

Comment: @GeekGirl - How about you create a function like Splitlist that takes a csv and returns a table. so you could go something like this 

WHERE MyColum in (Select * from(dbo.fn_splitlist(@MyParameter,','))

this way you can pass the following 'var1,var2,var3' as MyParameter

Comment: Checkout Jeff's DelmitedSplit8K... http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Answer (score 1):

create the following function.. a simple function that takes accepts a string.. along with the separator and spits out a table

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[F_SplitList](@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))
RETURNS @Results TABLE (value nvarchar(4000))
AS

    BEGIN
    DECLARE @INDEX INT
    DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(4000)
    -- HAVE TO SET TO 1 SO IT DOESNT EQUAL Z
    --     ERO FIRST TIME IN LOOP
    SELECT @INDEX = 1

    IF @String IS NULL RETURN
    WHILE @INDEX !=0


        BEGIN    
            -- GET THE INDEX OF THE FIRST OCCURENCE OF THE SPLIT CHARACTER
            SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)
            -- NOW PUSH EVERYTHING TO THE LEFT OF IT INTO THE SLICE VARIABLE
            IF @INDEX !=0
                SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)
            ELSE
                SELECT @SLICE = @STRING
            -- PUT THE ITEM INTO THE RESULTS SET
            INSERT INTO @Results(value) VALUES(@SLICE)
            -- CHOP THE ITEM REMOVED OFF THE MAIN STRING
            SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)
            -- BREAK OUT IF WE ARE DONE
            IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Then you can call your Where like this:

```
WHERE MyColum in (Select * from(dbo.F_SplitList(@MyParameter,','))
```

pass your MyParameter values like this: 'var1,var2,var3'

Answer (score 0):

As always, the answer is, "it depends". So, first thing... The syntax you're currently displaying

```
WHERE MyColum IN (@MyParameter)
```

is going to fail if you try to pass more than a single value. If you wan't to pass a comma separated list or array from the application, you'll first need to parse the string into separate values. If you're using SQL Serve 2016 or Azure, then the task is a breeze. Just use the STRING_SPLIT function. If you not you'll want to find a good string splitter. My favorite is [Jeff Moden's DelimitedSlit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) or if you're comfortable CRL assemblies, [Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/sqlclr-string-splitting-part-2-even-faster-even-more-scalable/) has one that is supposedly faster than anything around...

So, that problem #1 solved... Problem #2, You want to essentially ignore the filter altogether if a specific value is contained in the string of values...

Again, finding the value becomes quite easy once the string split. You disable the filter, using an OR @SomeParameter = MagicValue.

The following should illustrate idea...

```
DECLARE @ValuesList VARCHAR(1000) = '-1,1048309,1308584,1491312,1959807,2024608,2428302,2552655,2617456,2623776';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ParameterValues', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #ParameterValues;

SELECT Item = CAST(sc.Item AS INT) INTO #ParameterValues FROM dbo.SplitCSVToTable8K(@ValuesList, ',') sc;

DECLARE @GetAll BIT = 0;  -- ( -1 is the "all" value from the input string )
SELECT @GetAll = 1 FROM #ParameterValues pv WHERE pv.Item = 1;

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    sys.sysobjects o
    LEFT JOIN #ParameterValues pv
        ON o.id = pv.Item
WHERE 
    (
        pv.Item IS NOT NULL
        OR 
        @GetAll = 1
    )
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Please note the use of OPTION(RECOMPILE) in the query. Using "optional parameters" like this will cause the optimizer to ignore any SEEK execution plan options. OPTION(RECOMPILE) allows the optimizer to wait & see what, if any, value gets passed to the parameter before creating the plan, allowing a seek operation.

Answer (score 0):

yeah in this situation yo have to have split function and do as explained here.

Other way of doing this,

```
declare @MyParameter varchar(50)='1,2,3'
declare @Sql nvarchar(max)=''


set @Sql=
N'SELECT *  FROM HumanResources.Employee
WHERE BusinessEntityID IN ('+@MyParameter+')'
exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@MyParameter1 varchar(50)', @MyParameter1 = @MyParameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestGetDataInParameter] @MyParameter nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
declare @str nvarchar(MAX)
set @str = 'SELECT *  FROM MyTable
WHERE MyColum IN ('+@MyParameter+')'
exec(@str)
print @str
END

exec [TestGetDataInParameter] "'abc','xyz'"
```